# Is there any efficient way (library or function or algorithm) to delete or append specific row and column component in Compressed Sparse Row format?

Tags: c, sparse-matrix

Is there any efficient way (library or function or algorithm) to delete or append specific row and column component in Compressed Sparse Row format??

I'm using intel compiler however there are no any function to do that in Math Kernel Library.

So I need any information to delete or to append specific row and column data in CSR format.

Comment: Probably a question to ask on [Intel Math Library Forum](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-oneAPI-Math-Kernel-Library/bd-p/oneapi-math-kernel-library).

Comment: Assuming your CSR format has the same 3 arrays as the Python/scipy implementation, this action requires changing values in all 3 from the insertion point to the end.  The `data` and `indices` arrays will change in length (with the new data value and column index), and the `indptr` will have to be adjusted to account for that change.  A change in row number changes the length of `indptr` array.  CSR is designed for efficient calculation (esp. matrix multiplication), not for editing like this.